# Custom Edit Controller and View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, edit, parameters

I have set up a custom Rails new action (to hack around a particular solution) which works fine but there is a problem when there is an error in the form and I need to capture the previous values in the edit action.

So the question is, on an unsuccessful creation, how can I capture the parameters and plug these back into the edit view?

Form action:

```
def go
  begin
    @quote = Quote.new
    @quote.create_with_custom_params(params)
    @quote.save!
  rescue Exception => ex
    flash[:error] = "an error occured"
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end
```

Form view (minimised):

```
<%= form_tag :controller => :quoter, :action => :go do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, :placeholder => "quote name" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save quotation" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= text_field_tag :name, nil, :placeholder => "quote name" %>
```

use:

```
<%= text_field_tag :name, @quote.name, :placeholder => "quote name" %>
```